# Python: use xmlrpc module with a server requiring authentication

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, rpc, xml-rpc

I want to query an XML-RPC server using Python script.

First obstacle was that the server uses authentication, and I had to resort to requests.Session to overcome this. Now I did, and I can query the server over RPC, but I'm using *rather ugly* mechanism to do it - glueing strings. This, of course, produces just XML data, which I would again have to process manually to convert it into usable list or dictionary.

I found there's an xmlrpc module for Python which allows to cleanly work with a server; however, I can't find how to auth myself prior to using XML-RPC.

Here's the code that I already wrote, using requests:

```
from requests import Session

myserver_address='http://myserver.test.com/admin'
myserver_RPC=myserver_address+'?RPC2'
myserver_header={'Content-Type': "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"}
myserver_login={"srvAction":"LoginAdmin", "login":"testuser", "password":"testpassword", "Submit":"Login", "select_locale":"en"}
myserver_login2={"srvAction":"LoginOrg", "selectSection":"20", "submit":"Continue"}

method_header = '<methodCall xmlns:ex="http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/namespaces/extensions"><methodName>'
param_header = '</methodName><params>'
param_body_header = '<param><value><string>'
param_body_footer = '</string></value></param>'
method_footer = '</params></methodCall>'

def myserver_get_xml(myserver_method, myserver_method_param):
    param_body = ''

    for param in myserver_method_param:
        param_body = param_body + param_body_header + str(param) + param_body_footer

    myserver_post = method_header + myserver_method + param_header + param_body + method_footer
    page = s.post(myserver_RPC, myserver_post)
    return page.text

s = Session()
s.get(myserver_address)
s.post(myserver_address, myserver_login) 
s.post(myserver_address, myserver_login2)

s.headers.update(myserver_header)

result_xml = myserver_get_xml('myserverServer.getNetworkTree', ['31', ] )
print(result_xml)
```

So the question is:

- how to use xmlrpc module within an authenticated session?
- if that's not possible, is there something nice to convert XML into dictionary (preferrably) or list?

Example output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodResponse xmlns:ex="http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/namespaces/extensions"><params><param><value><array><data><value><array><data><value>10.0.0.0/16</value><value><i4>1</i4></value><value>31</value></data></array></value><value><array><data><value>10.1.0.0/16</value><value><i4>2</i4></value><value>31</value></data></array></value></data></array></value></param></params></methodResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks to @Bernhard, I figured how to use combined option: instead of the ugly _myserver_get_xml_ function, I now import _xmlrpc.client_ and use _xmlrpc.client.dumps_ function as follows: _page_test = s.post(myserver_RPC, xmlrpc.client.dumps( params=('31', ), methodname='myserverServer.getNetworkTree'))_. Works well enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement your own `xmlrpclib.Transport` class and specify that as your transport parameter when you instantiated the xmlrpclib.ServerProxy. See the example of a proxied transport implementation on https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#example-of-client-usage. 
You probably have to implement and modified `Transport.make_connection` only, which needs to return an `httplib.HTTPConnection` instance which has the *Cookie* header set from the http response headers from your login actions. You can't really use the `Session` class to make requests, as it is not compatible with the httplib.HTTPConnection class that is used by the rest of the `Transport` class methods. So to keep things simple, you might be able to perform the login with a `Session` instance, extract the headers (in particular the cookie header) and create an HTTPConnection with these headers.

```
def create_session_headers():
      s = requests.Session()
      # perform your request.Session creation with the login posts
      # return headers from the loggedin session
      return s.headers

class SessionTransport(xmlrpclib.Transport):
    def make_connection(self, host):
          # create the standard connection
          connection = super(SessionTransport, self).make_connection(host)
          session_headers = create_session_headers()
          for key, value in session_headers.items():
              connection.putheader(key, value)
          return connection

 service = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_address, SessionTransport())
```

I'm not sure if it will work like this, I haven't tested it. I hope it gives you enough information to try this approach.

Comment: Call me dense, but while it sounds very nice, I'm at loss on how to do it. Any chance you can write at least some pseudo-code for it? I should be able to take it from there then.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example that might do what you need.

Comment: So, it's probably closer - unfortunately, whatever I try to do I get _"TypeError: request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request_body'"_ all the time. The request I'm trying to do is: service.system.listMethods(). I've just spent some 3 hours trying to figure out how the library is supposed to work, but I'm not a Jedi yet :( Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Can't edit previous comment, but I just realized that:
 _service = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_address, SessionTransport)_
should be  _service = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_address, SessionTransport() )_ - took me some time to realize that :D It still doesn't work, but I'm one step closer :D

Comment: Yet one step closer: after changing to _for key, value in session_headers.items()_ I now get: _http.client.CannotSendHeader_ error on doing _service.system.listMethods()_. I'm afraid that copying headers won't work - I think that the server just tracks 5-tuple to identify the connection after login. It needs to be the very same connection at all times. I tried skipping headers (which are just _{'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/3.4.1 Windows/7', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}_) and it just says that admin is not logged in.

Comment: I assume you only need to keep the cookie header. Guessing from what you posted in your question, I would assume the server response to the login post messages contains a cookie header. This cookie needs to be set on the connection. Do you see the cookie header in the session object headers dict? BTW, I've updated the code above with fixes for the issues you mentioned. Sorry about that, I haven't tested the code.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution a while ago, works so far. It's very crude and not suitable to processing XML, but since I need just some data out of the app, it works.

```
#!/cygdrive/c/Python34/python.exe

from requests import Session
import sys
import json
import xmltodict

myserver_address='http://myserver.test.com/admin'
myserver_RPC=myserver_address+'?RPC2'
myserver_header={'Content-Type': "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"}
myserver_login={"srvAction":"LoginAdmin", "login":"testuser", "password":"testpassword", "Submit":"Login", "select_locale":"en"}
myserver_login2={"srvAction":"LoginOrg", "selectSection":"20", "submit":"Continue"}

s = Session()
s.get(myserver_address)
s.post(myserver_address, myserver_login) 
s.post(myserver_address, myserver_login2)

s.headers.update(myserver_header)

myserverMethod = '<methodCall xmlns:ex="http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/namespaces/extensions"><methodName>myserverMyViewUsage.getMyViewChildrenArray</methodName><params><param><value><int>602</int></value></param></params></methodCall>'
subnet_list = s.post(myserver_RPC, myserverMethod)
subnet_dictionary_coarse = xmltodict.parse(subnet_org_list.text)

#print( json.dumps(subnet_org_dictionary_coarse, indent=2))

for subnet_org_dictionary in subnet_org_dictionary_coarse['methodResponse']['params']['param']['value']['array']['data']['value']:
<put code here>
```

Make no mistake, this is basically raping XML to get the data I need; it's a "quick and very dirty" hack.